# instruction to enable ftp_ssl_connect on a LAMP stack

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying to work with `ftp_ssl_connect` function (on LAMP Stack) for connecting to ftps (not sftp) site(s). I check for openssl instillation, and is available. I un-commented `extension=php_openssl.dll`, and that gave me the following error.

Error Message:

`PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

SSL not working`

when I comment out `extension=php_openssl.dll`, I get the error message `SSL not working.`

How do I enable SSL or make SSL work?

Comment: Why are you looking for a dll on a lamp stack?  Am I missing something?

Comment: kafuka, that was the only record i found for openssl. I know that .dll is a windows environment file. I did not know where else to look for other than php.ini. Practically I'm looking for a pointer to what other settings file might contain this info. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `L` in `LAMP` means Linux, and the .dll files are for Windows. You need to install php_openssl package from yum or apt or ports or whatever your linux distro uses. You might just need to find the line in either php.ini or extensions.ini for openssl.so and uncomment that.

Comment: Sammitch, thank you, I understand .dll is windows extension, but i did not know where else to look for other than php.ini, I will check extensions.ini.